# what's the infix priority of type annotation (::)

Tags: haskell

What's the priority of `::`, is there any operator has even lower priority than it?

It seems the priority of `::` is lower than `$`, because both of the expression below returns `"ab"`

```
map head $ ["alice", "bob"] :: String
map head ["alice", "bob"] :: String
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The `::` part is called a type annotation.

A message on the mailing list points to exactly the same conclusion, supported by the grammar:

https://mail.haskell.org/pipermail/beginners/2012-December/011017.html

> It's not really a binary operator.
>
> It's part of the syntax, so it has no exact precedence, but since you're 
>   asking about it, I presume you're not interested in type declarations
>
> ```
> foo :: Int -> Double  
> foo = sin . fromIntegral
> ```
>
> but rather in expression type signatures. The production in the context-free 
>   syntax is
>
> ```
> exp → infixexp :: [context =>] type
> ```
>
> so the signature is for the entire infix expression:
>
> ```
> Prelude> toEnum . floor $ 12.7 + toEnum 73 :: Char
> 'U'
> ```
>
> hence if it had a precedence, it would be below 0 (the precedence of ($)).
>
> But be aware that
>
> "The grammar is ambiguous regarding the extent of lambda abstractions,
>   let  expressions, and conditionals. The ambiguity is resolved by the
>   meta-rule that  each of these constructs extends as far to the right
>   as possible."
>
> thus
>
> ```
> Prelude> (\x -> x + x :: Int -> Int) 2
>
> <interactive>:16:10:
>     No instance for (Num (Int -> Int)) arising from a use of `+'
>     Possible fix: add an instance declaration for (Num (Int -> Int))
>     In the expression: x + x :: Int -> Int
>     In the expression: \ x -> x + x :: Int -> Int
>     In the expression: (\ x -> x + x :: Int -> Int) 2
> ```
>
> the type signature here extends only over the `x + x`, since it is
>   parsed as a  part of the lambda abstraction
>
> [ `\x -> (x + x :: Int -> Int)` extends farther to the right than just 
>   `\x -> x + x` ]
>
> So if you want to give a type signature to a lambda abstraction, you
>   need  explicit parentheses:
>
> ```
> Prelude> ((\x -> x + x) :: Int -> Int) 2 4
> ```

Comment: Is there any situation where it doesn't behave as it were `infix (-1) ::`?

Comment: I don't think so, the second example in that message seems to work exactly the same way with `$`.